# Error while configuring apache tomcat 8.0.44 on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I've successfully installed java 1.8.0 and the runtime environment. After configuring some global variables in the setting (such as setting CATALINA_HOME, CLASSPATH and Path) and running tomcat/bin/startup, I received many error messages in the console starting as:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundExceptiong: C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat\logs\catalina.2018-03-27.log (access denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
....
etc etc
```

Where should I start fixing this? Is it a problem with my java runtime? Both JRE and Tomcat I have are 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely resulting from your file location. Try the following steps:

- Confirm that your Tomcat folder is written down accurately.
- If it is correctly located in the folder you have mentioned, try moving your Tomcat folder to another location outside of your Program Files. The issue is most likely caused by lack of administrator access while trying to work with your program in a locked location (Program Files).
- If you absolutely need to have your Tomcat in your Program Files directory, run your IDE/Terminal in Administrator mode to override access privileges for the Program Files directory.